# Singular or plural in possessives with "of" and "and"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, conjunctions, possessives

Let me explain my question with an example.

I am writing a paper in electrical engineering. We have two type A converters and one type B converter. Each converter has a control loop with a bandwidth. I want to say that all the bandwidths are selected as 5000. Should I say:

> The **bandwidth** of the type A and the type B control loops **is** set to 5000

or

> The **bandwidths** of the type A and the type B control loops **are** set to 5000

Comment: Either is fine. If the two types were set to different values, then "bandwidth" might be confusing, but in this case, there's no confusion.

Comment: @ColinFine said pretty much what I was going to say but better. I'd most likely opt for the first one, since, as Colin said, the bandwidth for both types is the same.

Comment: If we use the second sentence (plural), doesn't it indicate that each control loop has more than one bandwidth, which is not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bandwidth is the same, I'll definitely go with the first option.

Here are similar statements where it may seem more 'natural':

- The current time(*) in New York and New Jersy 10:00 P.M.
- All the slides have an angle(*) of 30 degrees
- The color(*) of the lakes is greenish this time of the year